# Why does it shows error while running ConnectedThresholdImageFilter example?

Tags: itk

I am trying to run ConnectedThresholdImageFilter example in ITK mentioned "https://itk.org/Doxygen45/html/Segmentation_2ConnectedThresholdImageFilter_8cxx-example.html" here.

But it is showing the following error.

> itk::ImageFileWriterException (0x24cb740)
>
> Location: "void itk::ImageFileWriter::Write() [with
>   TInputImage = itk::Image]"  File:
>   /usr/local/include/ITK-4.13/itkImageFileWriter.hxx Line: 151
>   Description:  Could not create IO object for writing file output
>   Tried to create one of the following:
>       BMPImageIO
>       BioRadImageIO
>       Bruker2dseqImageIO
>       GDCMImageIO
>       GE4ImageIO
>       GE5ImageIO
>       GiplImageIO
>       HDF5ImageIO
>       JPEGImageIO
>       LSMImageIO
>       MINCImageIO
>       MRCImageIO
>       MetaImageIO
>       NiftiImageIO
>       NrrdImageIO
>       PNGImageIO
>       StimulateImageIO
>       TIFFImageIO
>       VTKImageIO   You probably failed to set a file suffix, or
>       set the suffix to an unsupported type

I didn't do any changes in code. And I am trying to use dicom image as an input.

Answer (score 0):

It is either

1. You set the output file name with an unsupported extension.
2. There is something wrong about how you compiled/linked ITK or how you are linking your example to ITK.